# unicode format error

Tags: python

So, I just started mining twitter data using its python twitter api.
And was about to plot the tweet stucture
But I am getting this error

```
    f.write('strict digraph {\n%s\n}' % (';\n'.join(dot),))
     UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 108: 
    ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is the code..

```
def draw_tweet_graph(g):
OUT = "graph.dot"
try: 
    nx.drawing.write_dot(g, OUT)
except ImportError, e:

    dot = ['"%s" -> "%s" [tweet_id=%s]' % (n1, n2, g[n1][n2]['tweet_id']) \
        for n1, n2 in g.edges()]
    f = open(OUT, 'w') 
    f.write('strict digraph {\n%s\n}' % (';\n'.join(dot),))
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [`codecs.open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) for your file.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Which encoding did you give it?

Comment: I just changed the line from open to codecs.open() after importing codecs modue. do you think i should do str(dot) in the last line where it is join(dot)